# JQuery selector to exclude certain elements?

Tags: jquery, web-scraping

I need jquery to pull everything on a webpage containing the @ sign but not containing a certain email address.

So what I have is that is should contain the element

*:contains("@")

and then the actions that it takes should be to extract element contents

a[href^="mailto:"]

I am lost how to input not to pull anything with the specific email address. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle please with an example please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this to your selector:

```
:not(:contains("blah@blah.com"))')
```